# Allow read access via [] while granting write access only to subclasses

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
class A {
  private:
    std::vector<int> v_;
  protected:
    int& operator[](int idx) { return (v_.at(idx)); }; //[1]
  public:
    A(): v_(5) {}
    const int& operator[](int idx) const {return (v_.at(idx)); }; //[2]
};

int main() {
  A myA;
  const A myB;
  //std::cout << myA[1] << std::endl; //does not work [3]
  std::cout << myB[1] << std::endl; //does work [4]
}
```

Suppose I want to have `operator[]` to work in the following way:

1. It should provide a read only interface to obtain the *`i`th* element of the member vector `[2]`.
2. Derived classes should however be allowed to use `operator[]` also to write some data into the vector. `[1]`

With these signatures I cannot define a non-const object and access it `[3]`. If I however delete the protected interface `[2]`, line `[3]` would work. Why is this the case?

So what are my options to achieve the desired behaviour? Do I have to move `v_` to `protected` and assess it  directly from my sub-classes?

Comment: @Ðаn I suspect OP expected overload resolution to take into account access modifiers.

Comment: Isn't it "better" to provide another function altogether? Because `(*this)[index]` is a bit of a pain to write instead of `get(index)`, no?

Comment: Have you considered just not using inheritance? Having to ask these questions could be an indicator that you are simply shoe-horning inheritance where it's not a good fit. protected is very rarely a good idea. The same goes with splitting const vs mutable interfaces across base/derived.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Yes indeed it is very likely that I am over-engineering. So which pattern should I use for the following case: I have a base class with a container, which I want to encapsulate. The client should have read-only access. My derived classes will populate the container, hence they need write access to the container. My class will be later used in a factory. So how to implement this interface properly?